# 'Accept Cookies' on TradingView

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I have previously created a script to 'Accept Cookies' on TradingView website (https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-TSLA/financials-income-statement/), as follows:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Accept all']"))).click()
```

This used to work perfectly fine. The 'Accept Cookies' popup window will appear (bottom left on page) when the webpage is **initially** loaded and the script above will execute, locate and click the "Accept All" button when the popup appears and continues with my script, but recently the website has updated and the above script no longer works and python selenium is unable to find this element and click on it.

The update on TradingView for 'Accept Cookies' popup window now only appears if the user manually scrolls down the webpage (around halfway down), therefore one cannot just simply use `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` function to wait for the popup to appear and for the webpage to fully load all the elements.

I have added this code `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")` to my script prior to accepting cookies to manually scroll the webpage down to the bottom of the page to force the 'Accept Cookies' window to appear, which it does. But unfortunately the script is still unable to click on 'Accept All', so not sure what I'm missing here, as I can clearly see this element when inspecting HTML elements as shown below post scrolling webpage to bottom of page:

[image: Image of TradingView Accept Cookies window appearing and the inspect element]

Out of curiosity, I tried to run the main script without adding the 'Accept cookies' script mentioned at the start, and the script runs fine until the window pops up half way down, and it then disrupts the entire script from scraping. Therefore I need to ensure this window is first removed prior to scraping. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I have read from other posts that this might be due to shadow DOM (although I don't know much about this), but after inspecting elements it doesn't seem to be the case, I have also tried using CSS selector script `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "acceptAll-WvyPjcpY button-OvB35Th_ size-xsmall-OvB35Th_ color-brand-OvB35Th_ variant-primary-OvB35Th_").click()` instead of XPath but this didn't work

Comment: I just loaded it and didn't see it. It might be a GDPR thing that only EU sees. If so you can try a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I forgot to mention that this happens when user is logged in, and the login is required in order to see all the data. Yes I am based in Europe

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try. this will scroll slowly and click the button when it appears

```
driver.execute_async_script("""
let interval = setInterval(() => {
  let span = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')].find(span => span.innerText.match("Accept all"))
  if(span){
    span.click()
    clearInterval(interval)
    arguments[0]()
  } else {
    window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 100)
  }
}, 1000)
""")
```

Comment: Thanks pguardiario. I tried this but unfortunately the results are the same whereby the webpage will scroll all the way down, but it is unable to identify the 'Accept All' in the cookie banner and click on it

Comment: Maybe it's spelled different or maybe it's in an iframe

Comment: Not sure what you mean by spelled different. The span text is certainly showing 'Accept all' and I checked the html elements to see if I can find any <iframe> elements and there were not any, or any shadowroots, so its quite strange how a normal search element by xpath or via cas selector doesnt seem to work